# ¿Cómo puedo determinar la cantidad de símbolos que hay en un input?

Tags: python, input

Se me pide contar símbolos y espacios por separados en un texto ingresado por input en python ¿Cómo puedo determinar la cantidad de símbolos que hay en un input?

Solo logre contar los espacios con el código de abajo

```
def check_space(string): 
     count = 0
     for i in range(0, len(a)): 
           
         
         if a[i] == " ": 
             count += 1
           
     return count 
   
 a=str(input("Ingrese una frase "))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar un bloque `if-else` preguntando si la letra actual es `espacio`, `isalpha()`, `isnumeric()`, etc... Ver [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum)

```
def contar_caracter(frase):
    contador = [0, 0, 0] # letras/numeros, espacios, simbolos
    for c in frase:
        if c.isalnum():
            contador[0] += 1
        elif c == ' ':
            contador[1] += 1
        else:
            contador[2] += 1
    return contador
```

Ahora haciendo una prueba:

```
prueba = "Lorem ipsum 83 dolor ¿sit amet?. Consectetur, 32!!"
alnum, esp, simb = contar_caracter(prueba)
print(f'Letras y numeros: {alnum}, Espacios: {esp}, Simbolos: {simb}')
```

> `Letras y numeros: 37, Espacios: 7, Simbolos: 6`

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Podrías analizar letra por letra en tu frase y luego definir los símbolos que deseas contar

Para obtener cada letra o caracter especial en tu frase puedes utilizar lo siguiente

```
for letra in frase:
```

Y para verificar si deseas contar o no la letra o caracter especial puedes comparar la letra con una lista, de la siguiente forma (Nota, tendrías que agregar todos los símbolos que deseas contar por separado en la lista)

```
if letra in [' ', '.', ',', '¿', '?', ';', ':']:
```

Luego puedes utilizar un diccionario para guardar el caracter especial que deseas contar y el número de veces que se repite dentro de tu frase

```
contador[letra] = contador.get(letra, 0) + 1
```

Esta línea lo que hace es, intentar obtener la letra dentro de un diccionario que llamé `contador` si no existe entonces la inicializa con 0 y el `+ 1` es para incrementar cada vez que encuentre el carcter deseado

Ejemplo completo:

```
def check_string(frase):
    contador = {}
    for letra in frase:
        if letra in [' ', '.', ',', '¿', '?', ';', ':', '"']:
            contador[letra] = contador.get(letra, 0) + 1
    return contador
   
check_string(input("Ingrese una frase "))
```

Si ingresamos la frase: "Un hombre con ideas nuevas es un loco, hasta que sus ideas triunfan". Marcelo Bielsa

Esto produce:

```
{'"': 2, ' ': 14, ',': 1, '.': 1}
```